# Using "would" in the First Conditional

Tags: grammar

I know that the following sentence is correct:

If it rains, I will stay at home.

My question is **if the following sentence is also correct when you are not so sure about what you are going to do**:

**If it rains, I would stay at home.**

I've seen 'It wouldn't surprise me if it were true.'
Above sentence is using "would" instead of "will". 
Is this a very special case? Or it is natural and means we can use "would" instead of "will" when we are not so sure?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What the poster is looking for is "If it rains, I might stay home."

Comment: Thank you very much for replying so quickly. I think original example was bad.
I should have written the below sentence instead of 'It wouldn't surprise me if it were true.' "I wouldn't be surprised if he gives us a membership."
Above sentence is found in the following link:
https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/664bb77c-3fa4-420e-aa82-b5a4796d6e88

Answer (score 1):

After looking it over a little, I found that using `would` makes your other verbs take passive tense.

Your example has the past tense `were` being used which is why `would` is used.
In order to change it to use `will` you would have to say, "It will surprise me if it is true."

If it rain(s), I will stay at home.
If it rained, I would stay at home.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is an issue of verb tense continuity.

"If it rains, I will stay at home."  becomes "If it were to rain, I would stay at home."

In the other example "It wouldn't surprise me if it were true" with the word will would be "It won't surprise me if it is true"